# How to write a rule for total assimilation of sounds?

Tags: phonology, comparative-linguistics

I am looking at this list of words; the first column is from Sanskrit, and the second is from a daughter language Prakrit.

1. sapta > satta
2. dugdha > duddha
3. udgāra > uggāla
4. tikta > titta
5. mudga > mugga
6. ardha > addha
7. karpata > kappada
8. kurkura > kukkura
9. darpa > dappa
10. parṇa > paṇṇa
11. karma > kamma
12. sapta > satta
13. sakta > satta
14. sarva > savva

The specific sound changes I am looking at are p > t, g > d, d > g, k > t, r > d, r > k, r > ṇ, r > m, r > v. These are all cases of unconditioned total assimilation. How would I write a single phonological rule that covers this scenario?

Comment: This is covered in a paper by Hankamer and Aissen: https://babel.ucsc.edu/~hank/jh.papers/hank_and_aissen74.pdf